# Can't figure out how to insert an image into blueJ

Tags: java, image, jpeg, bluej

This is what my professor gave us. He also said that this code assumes we have an image already in the directory. I don't know how to put an image into the directory...

Adding an Image
You must import additional packages at the top of your source file for the example to compile.

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
```

The following code uses some advanced features not covered in the book to display a JPEG or GIF image.  This assumes you have an image in the directory of your BlueJ project called “MyPhoto.jpg” but you should replace this with the actual name of your image.

```
BufferedImage photo = null;
try {
File file = new File("MyPhoto.jpg");
photo = ImageIO.read(file);
} catch (IOException e){
g.drawString("Problem reading the file", 100, 100);
}
g.drawImage(photo, 10, 10, 150, 225, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

adding a photo to the directory means:

if your java file is located at "C:\Program Files\Java" then you must also add a file named MyPhoto.jpg into the same folder.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Java" is maybe not the best example for this, as it can be easily confused (especially by beginners) with the installation directory of the jdk.

Comment: @Danielle if this answer solved you problem please click the check mark next to it. I'm glad I could help!